# GoogleSheets: How can I sort sheets on a cell in each sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I create a different sheet for each client (in Google-sheets). Each tab is a different sheet for a different client.
So I create a different client invoice in each tab. When an invoice is paid, the cell (Total-Owing) is zero. How can I sort the tabs (sheets) on the value of the cell on each sheet that tells me the Total-Owing?
i.e Sort all the tabs (sheets) where there is money owing, so I don't have to click through all the hundreds of sheets to find each customer that has not paid.
Or...
Can you suggest a better way to keep my invoicing in Google-Sheets?

Comment: Hello! It's always the exact same cell in each sheet?

Comment: Well not yet. I cannot think of any other way to sort all the sheets where money is owing. I guess I'll have to create the same cell in every sheet. Not ideal because if I add a row then the sort will no longer work for that sheet, amd I will not know.

Comment: At this point your question is too broad, please edit it to a specific question about sheets.  Please see:  [How do I ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that employs `Array.sort()` and `Spreadsheet.moveActiveSheet()`, like this:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  sortSheets_(e);
}


////////////////////////////////
// [START modifiable parameters]
const magic = {
  cellToSortBy: 'A1',
  rowToWatch: 3,
  columnToWatch: 4,
  sheetsToKeepInFront: ['Dashboard', 'Settings',],
};
// [END modifiable parameters]
////////////////////////////////


/**
* Sorts sheets into the order given by magic.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function sortSheets_(e) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 5 November 2022
  //  - see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/167609/269219
  if (e.range.rowStart !== magic.rowToWatch
    && e.range.columnStart !== magic.columnToWatch) {
    return;
  }
  const sheets = e.source.getSheets();
  const sheetProps = getSheetProps_(sheets);
  sheetProps.sort(sortCriteria_);
  if (sheetProps.every((sheetProp, index) => sheetProp.position === index + 1)) {
    return;
  }
  showMessage_('Sorting sheets...');
  sheetProps.forEach((sheetProp, index) => {
    const newPosition = index + 1;
    if (newPosition !== sheetProp.position) {
      moveSheetToPosition_(sheetProp.sheet, newPosition);
    }
  });
  e.range.activate();
  showMessage_('Done. Sheets were sorted into a new order.');
}


/**
* Gets sheets, their names, positions, sortKeys, and an indicator
* of whether a sheet should be kept as one of the first ones
* in the tab bar.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet[]} sheets The sheets to process.
* @return {Object[]} An array of objects that each describe a sheet.
*/
function getSheetProps_(sheets) {
  return sheets.map((sheet, index) => {
    const name = sheet.getName();
    const keepInFront = magic.sheetsToKeepInFront.indexOf(name);
    return {
      sheet: sheet,
      name: name,
      position: index + 1,
      sortKey: Math.sign(sheet.getRange(magic.cellToSortBy).getDisplayValue().length),
      keepInFront: keepInFront,
    };
  });
}


/**
* Determines the sort order of sheets.
* Use as compareFunction with Array.sort().
*
* @param {Object} a A sheetProps object.
* @param {Object} b A sheetProps object.
* @return {Number} -1 if a comes first, 1 if b comes first, 0 if they are sort-wise equal.
*/
function sortCriteria_(a, b) {
  switch (true) {
    case a.keepInFront !== -1 && b.keepInFront !== -1:
      return a.keepInFront - b.keepInFront;
    case a.keepInFront !== -1:
      return -1;
    case b.keepInFront !== -1:
      return 1;
    case a.sortKey < b.sortKey:
      return -1;
    case a.sortKey > b.sortKey:
      return 1;
    default:
      return 0;
  }
}


/**
* Moves a sheet to the given position in the tab bar.
*
* @param {Sheet} sheet A sheet in a spreadsheet.
* @param {Number} position The 1-indexed position in the tab bar.
*/
function moveSheetToPosition_(sheet, position) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
  ss.moveActiveSheet(position);
}


/**
* Shows a message in a pop-up.
*
* @param {String} message The message to show.
* @param {Number} timeoutSeconds Optional. The number of seconds before the message goes away. Defaults to 5.
*/
function showMessage_(message, timeoutSeconds) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(message, 'Sort sheets', timeoutSeconds || 5);
}
```